# Python script that efficiently drops columns from a CSV file

Tags: python

I have a csv file, where the columns are separated by tab delimiter but the number of columns is not constant. I need to read the file up to the 5th column. (I dont want to ready the whole file and then extract the columns, I would like to read for example line by line and skip the remaining columns)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use pandas nrows to read only a certain number of csv lines:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('out122.txt', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `usecols` argument in `pd.read_csv` to limit the number of columns to be read.

```
# test data
s = '''a,b,c
1,2,3'''
with open('a.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(s, file=f)


df1 = pd.read_csv("a.txt", usecols=range(1))
df2 = pd.read_csv("a.txt", usecols=range(2))


print(df1)
print()
print(df2)

# output
#   a
#0  1
#
#   a  b
#0  1  2
```